# Logic Apps - order of JSON objects in action "Data operations - Select"?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

When transforming JSON data using "Data operations - Select" the JSON object order is always alphabetical.
Example: {"Area": "12", "Cargo": "Yes", "Logistics": "No"}
Does any of you know if there is a way to set another order of the JSON objects? I know that the order is not an issue for JSON being valid, but for readability it would be good to be able to set the order.

Comment: did you check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Data operations - Compose" and make a new JSON with the order you would like.